# How to use visual leak detecter ( vld ) for com/atl dll projects?

Tags: com, atl, vldb

I included vld.h file in my activex dll project. when i try to compile my project from visual studio 2008.I am getting the following error,

1>Registering output...

1>Project : error PRJ0050: Failed to register output. Please ensure you have the appropriate permissions to modify the registry.

How to use visual leak detecter for com/activex dll projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with the 'visual leak detecter' (sic?)... I'm not familiar with it.

Anyway, the `PRJ0050` error occurs because Visual Studio attempts to auto-register the DLL generated by the project, using a post-build step (see Project Settings), and you are not logged in as a user with permission to modify the registry.

So, either Run Visual Studio as an administrator (if you're on Windows Vista), if you want to allow auto-registration, or remove the auto-registration post-build step from the project.